# I am having trouble with creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i was trying to create a new react project but i faced errors i never seen before i tried **npm cache clean --force** it said **npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.** so i tried this

npm cache verify
it responded with

```
it Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.013s
```

but i still cant create react app using the command  npx create-react-app projectName

it just responds with

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/html-entities reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/html-entities: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\u4\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-04T11_43_21_180Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting travel/ from C:\Users\u4\Desktop\code
Done.
```

i updated my node thinking that may be the problem  but still no change HELP!!

Comment: this may be a proxy issue try this, 
`npm cache clean --force`
`npm config rm proxy`
`npm config rm https-proxy`
`npm cache verify`
 `npx create-react-app projectName`

Comment: its still doesn't work.  it shows the same error  @MominRaza

Comment: try these solution first `npm cache clean --force` install react app globally `npm install -g create-react-app` now create react app by `npx create-react-app projctname` . If This solution also not work uninstall node and install latest node JS stable version you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

so i found the source to my problem. first i runed **npm -g list** and it only had **npm** no  create-react-app so you need to install it using **npm install -g create-react-app**. check it by running **npm -g list** if successfully installed create-react-app will be their. now you can run npx create-react-app projctname with out a problem.